# Laravel 5.3 Update with string containing question mark

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am currently trying to do an update to a field in my database. It is a simple text field and I am having issues if the string contains a question mark (?).

Example:

```
test ? test
```

What is happening is that it sees the '?' and thinks its a binding. When actually its just a question. I have tried wrapping a `\DB::raw()` around it but it does not work.

Has anyone else come across this before?

Comment: If it is string, give it quotes.

Comment: Can you not put it in double quotes then put a backslash before it like `"\?"`, not even sure you need the backslash i think just the quotes would be enough, it would be good to see more code though

Comment: I have ```\DB::raw("'{$description}'")``` but add a \ does nothing.

Comment: There seemed to have been some caching but the DB raw did work. I have not noticed this happening before so I am wandering if there is a encoding issue going on some where,

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to update this field?

Answer (score 0):

I have a quite similar problem, in my case, I am trying to save a url containing '?' to the database using eloquent. My workaround is to replace the '?' with another character, for example, a '^' when saving and the opposite when reading. I utilize the [eloquent mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators) to do that so in my eloquent model, I have something like this.

```
public function getFieldNameAttribute($value)
{
    return str_replace("^", "?", $value);
}

public function setFieldNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['field_name'] = str_replace("?", "^", $value);
}
```

However, you need to find a character that you can guarantee won't be in the value you are trying to save.